# Remove anchor from one category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, ce-1.9.2.2, topmenu

I have one category "A". Category A has two sub-categories B and C.Category A is coming in top menu under which two subcategories B and C are also coming. Its fine.

Now I want to remove anchor tag from category A but keep on B and C. How can this be achieved?

Comment: are you using RWD theme ? OR provide name of the theme

Comment: @AnilSuthar I am using Porto theme.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no way to remove the anchor tag from a menu node afaik without using a module or writing your own logic.

You need to look through the method:

```
_getHtml(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass)
```

In the class:

```
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu
```